# Limit number of response array in spring rest docs

Tags: spring, controller, httpresponse, spring-restdocs

I'm working on trying to use spring-rest-docs and scacap spring auto rest docs in order to generate my API documentations from unit tests.

I'm encountering the following issue:
I'm testing my getAll method which returns an array of objects. In http-response.adoc file I see all the objects printed. Let's say I have 100 entry in my collection it contains all 100 entries. I'd like to limit this to just print the first one. How can I achieve this?

As a small example I report a sample of the array with just 2 elments:

```
{
  "content" : [ {
    "createdOn" : "2020-05-13T16:40:12+02:00",
    "updatedOn" : "2020-05-13T16:40:12+02:00",
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "England"
  }, {
    "createdOn" : "2020-05-13T16:40:12+02:00",
    "updatedOn" : "2020-05-13T16:40:12+02:00",
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Italy"
  } ],
  "first" : true,
  "last" : true,
  "number" : 0,
  "numberOfElements" : 2,
  "size" : 10,
  "totalElements" : 2,
  "totalPages" : 1
}
```

I'd like that content array contains only the firs element it finds.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into REST Docs specifically for this task, but there is a general purpose mechanism for preprocessing the response to modify its content before it's documented. There's some guidance in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html5/#customizing-requests-and-responses-preprocessors-writing-your-own) about implementing your own preprocessor and modifying the content of a request or response:

> If one of the built-in preprocessors does not meet your needs, you can write your own by implementing the OperationPreprocessor interface. You can then use your custom preprocessor in exactly the same way as any of the built-in preprocessors.
>
> If you want to modify only the content (body) of a request or response, consider implementing the `ContentModifier` interface and using it with the built-in `ContentModifyingOperationPreprocessor`.

In your case, your `ContentModifier` would use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to read the JSON from the response body into a `Map<String, Object>`. It would then remove all but the first item from the `array` under the `content` key. This modified map can then be written back to a `byte[]` using the `ObjectMapper` and returned.